# How extract columns from json column in dataframe

Tags: r, json, jsonb

I have data extracted from PostgreSQL database with jsonb column, it looks like

```
df <- data.frame(item_id = c(1,2),
                 item_price = c(2,3),
                 jsonb=c('{"name": "1st item", "color": "red", "taste": "vanilla"}',
                         '{"name": "2nd item", "color": "blue", "foo": "bar"}'))
```

I want to extract `name` and `color` to have

```
  item_id item_price     name color
1       1          2 1st item   red
2       2          3 2nd item  blue
```

I know how to get it directly from database, but not from R dataframe.

P.S. Ronak Shah gave working solution. Is there any solution with some `json` library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jsonlite:

```
# Install pacakges if they are not already installed:

necessary_packages <- c("jsonlite")

# Create a vector containing the names of any packages needing installation:

new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in%
                                       installed.packages()[, "Package"])]

# If the vector has more than 0 values, install the new pacakges
# (and their) associated dependencies:

if (length(new_packages) > 0) {install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)}

# Initialise the packages in the session:

lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

# Unnest the json and store it column bind it with the original dataframe: 

cbind(df[,names(df) != "jsonb"], 
      do.call("rbind", lapply(paste0("[", df$jsonb ,"]"), 
        function(x){fromJSON(x, flatten = TRUE)[,c("name", "color")]})))
```

Comment: This is really close to what I need. I wonder if I can get from json only `name` and `color`, not all fields including `taste` and `foo`

Comment: @YuriyBarvinchenko edited as required please give my solution an upvote and accept it if you have found it useful.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use regex to extract the data you need :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(name = str_match(jsonb, '"name":(.*?),')[, 2], 
         color = str_match(jsonb, '"color":(.*?),')[, 2]) %>%
  select(-jsonb)

#  item_id item_price        name   color
#1       1          2  "1st item"   "red"
#2       2          3  "2nd item"  "blue"
```

Comment: Good approach, I like it.
and it's easy to remove quotes with `str_remove_all()`
```df %>%
  mutate(name = str_remove_all( str_match(jsonb, '"name":(.*?),')[, 2], '\"'),
         color = str_remove_all( str_match(jsonb, '"color":(.*?),')[, 2], '\"')) %>%
  select(-jsonb)```